# Not relying on a number being stored at index. method help

Tags: java

I've been asked to change the 'getlot' method in this class so that it doesn't rely on a lot with a particular number being stores at index [number -1] in the collection. e.g, if lot # 3 was deleted, then lot # 4 would have been changed from index 3 to 2. I've tried recoding but to no avail. Any help is appreciated. This is the method I code I've been trying to change. (lot is part of an array list) Thanks

```
    public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)
    {
    if((lotNumber >= 1) && (lotNumber < nextLotNumber)) {
        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(lotNumber - 1);
        if(selectedLot.getNumber() != lotNumber) {
            System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number " +
                               selectedLot.getNumber() +
                               " was returned instead of " +
                               lotNumber);
            selectedLot = null;
        }
        return selectedLot;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber +
                           " does not exist.");
        return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a map from `int` to `Lot`:

```
Map<Integer, Lot> lots = new HashMap<Integer, Lot>();

public Lot getLot(int lotNumber) {
    return lots.get(lotNumber);
}
```

You can than add some simplifying methods like this:

```
public void addLot(Lot lot) {
    if (lots.containsKey(lot.getNumber()) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lot " + lot + " already added");

    lots.put(lot.getNumber(), lot);
}

public void removeLot(int lotNumber) {
    if (lots.containsKey(lot.getNumber()) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lot with " +lotNumber+ " not added");

    return lots.remove(lotNumber); // will also return the lot 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that lots continue to be stored in order I suggest a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map`.  There are a variety of implementations of the `Map` interface (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html for example) which you can choose from depending on what other operations you need to support.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a sorted list of Lots you can use [binary search] to find it.[1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

```
public Lot getLot(int lotNumber) {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(lots, new Lot(lotNumber));
    if (index >= 0) {
        return lots.get(index);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Failed to find lot " + lotNumber);
        return null;
    }    

}
```

This assumes that Lot is easy to instantiate with an int and implements Comparable. Otherwise you could create a Comparator.

```
public class LotComparator implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        int num1 = generateInt(o1);
        int num2 = generateInt(o2);
        return num1 - num2;
    }

    private int generateInt(Object o) {
       if (o instanceof Lot) {
            Lot l = (Lot) o;
            return l.getNumber();
       }
       else {
            Integer i = (Integer) o;
            return i;
       }
}
```

As others have suggested using a Map from integer (lotNumber) to Lot is probably a better idea.